# Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B

Tags: windows, visual-studio, neo4j

Published neoj using visual studio 2017 and got `neoj.exe` file under `bin\Release\PublishOutput` but while running the `neoj.exe` file it throws:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException An attempt was
>   made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

and window show as dotnet has stopped working. Anyone plz Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you explain your context.
Are you trying to build your own Neo4j desktop ? Server ?
Neo4j is Java-based so why using .net

Comment: I'm working with neo cryptocurrency and have no idea about Neo4j. I have followed this link http://docs.neo.org/en-us/sc/getting-started-java.html. I'm keep getting above error while hit neon or neoj command in terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply Jerome. Found the problem i have been using windows 7. Works fine with windows 10.

Comment: :) So this is not about neo4j at all :)))))
Happy mining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was platform problem, i have been using windows 7 in which neoj or neon(neo compiler) doesn't support using visual studio 2017. After i tried in windows 10 it works properly.